# Java: how to exclude carriage return/ line feed from System.in.read

Tags: java, char

I am very new to this and working through a tutorial but wanted to fancy it up with a while loop so that the program repeats until "K" is entered by the user.
Unfortunately, this seems to read the carriage return and line feed when the incorrect char is entered. This means that "**WRONG**" is output three times instead of once.
Is there any way to exclude these so that only the Character is read? Thanks in advance

```
class Guess{

    public static void main(String args[])
    throws java.io.IOException {
        char ch, answer ='K';


        System.out.println("I'm thinking of a letter between A and Z.");
        System.out.print("Can you guess it:");
        ch = (char) System.in.read(); //read a char from the keyboard

        while (ch != answer) {
        System.out.println("**WRONG**");
        System.out.println ("I'm thinking of a letter between A and Z.");
        System.out.print("Can you guess it:");
        ch = (char) System.in.read(); //read a char from the keyboard
        if (ch == answer) System.out.println("**Right**");

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You could try using a do-while statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the statments order.
Try this

```
public class Guess {

    public static void main(String args[])
            throws java.io.IOException {
        char ch, answer = 'K';

        System.out.println("I'm thinking of a letter between A and Z.");
        System.out.print("Can you guess it:");
        ch = (char) System.in.read(); //read a char from the keyboard

        while (ch != answer) {


            ch = (char) System.in.read(); //read a char from the keyboard
            if (ch == answer) {
                System.out.println("**Right**");
                break;
            }else{
                System.out.println("**WRONG**");
            }
            System.out.println("I'm thinking of a letter between A and Z.");
            System.out.print("Can you guess it:");

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feed back have just made the amendments you suggested and this works !!

Comment: @TMC choose one of the answer as the right one for the others find it.

Comment: Didn't know I could do that, have done now, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `Scanner` and read the line when user hits return as `read` considers return as another character, e.g.:

```
char answer ='K';
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("I'm thinking of a letter between A and Z.");
System.out.print("Can you guess it:");
String ch = scanner.nextLine(); //read a char from the keyboard

while (ch.length() > 0 && ch.charAt(0) != answer) {
    System.out.println("**WRONG**");
    System.out.println ("I'm thinking of a letter between A and Z.");
    System.out.print("Can you guess it:");
    ch = scanner.nextLine();//read a char from the keyboard
}
System.out.println("**Right**");
scanner.close();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feed back, I will have to look into the Scanner function, I did however find that I got the same results with multiple lines although as the the other answer has pointed out my ordering is off so combined with ammending this it worked !